# Skip Over Error in Loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, loops, rss

I am trying to use Google's Feed API to get images using a feed inside of an AngularJS controller. It will successfully get three images then it will hit a twitter URL and it get's confused and breaks the script. I want it to skip over that and keep loading images. Is there anyway to do that?

Error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: submitted by <a href="http://www.reddit.com/user/lachlan_jp"> lachlan_jp </a> <br> <a href="https://twitter.com/caseandpointdjs/status/552222732994482178">[link]</a> <a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/Monstercat/comments/2rg0nr/case_points_new_single_will_be_premiering/">[8 comments]</a>
```

Code:

```
$http.get("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load", { params: { "v": "1.0", "q": "http://www.reddit.com/r/monstercat/.rss", "num": "100" } })
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.rssTitle = data.responseData.feed.title;
                $scope.rssUrl = data.responseData.feed.feedUrl;
                $scope.rssSiteUrl = data.responseData.feed.link;
                $scope.entries = data.responseData.feed.entries;

                var data = data.responseData.feed;

                var findFirstImage = data.entries.content;
                angular.forEach(data.entries, function(value){
                  value.sapleImage =     $(value.content).find('img').eq(0).attr('src');
                  console.log(value.sapleImage);
                })



            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log("ERROR: " + data);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using try:catch block that does nothing?

```
try {
$http.get("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load", { params: { "v": "1.0", "q": "http://www.reddit.com/r/monstercat/.rss", "num": "100" } })
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.rssTitle = data.responseData.feed.title;
                $scope.rssUrl = data.responseData.feed.feedUrl;
                $scope.rssSiteUrl = data.responseData.feed.link;
                $scope.entries = data.responseData.feed.entries;

                var data = data.responseData.feed;

                var findFirstImage = data.entries.content;
                angular.forEach(data.entries, function(value){
                  value.sapleImage =     $(value.content).find('img').eq(0).attr('src');
                  console.log(value.sapleImage);
                })



            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log("ERROR: " + data);
            });
    }
}
catch(err) {
    Console.log('Got an error'); // or just pass/continue/return true/any way of doing nothing
}
```

Comment: Wasn't aware this was a thing. I'll try it when I get home. Thanks!

Comment: hi @Drakee510, did you figure out this problem? I am doing something similar to you and trying to the get images from the RSS feed.

Comment: @carol1287 I've been away from home and internet and I haven't had the time to try this, but this my be the answer.

Comment: Hi @Drakee510, no worries thanks a lot. I test it and it actually works but I moved the try/catch inside the Angular forEach loop.